# parallel GNU make and rules that create several targets at once

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile, gnu-make

I have in my GNU makefile (among others) several rules of the form

```
a b c d: x
        program $^
```

i.e. `program` creates the files a, b, c and d with just one invokation.
When I run this with `gmake -j 4`, *make* spawns four `program` runs in parallel, because none of the files exist and none has a dependency on the other.

I can fix this by providing a "fake dependency chain" (for lack of a better term):

```
a: x
        program $^
b: a
c: b
d: c
```

Is there a more elegant way to teach gmake to run `program` only once, even in a parallel build?

**EDIT**: Any solution should obey the dependency on `x` and do nothing if `a - d` are up to date with respect to `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your targets all share a common stem, then you can use pattern rules:

```
%.a %.b %.c %.d:
        touch $*.a $*.b $*.c $*.d
```

If they don't then the only thing you can do is create a sentinel file:

```
a b c d: .sentinel ;
.sentinel: ; touch a b c d $@
```

Comment: No, the stem is different. But I tried compacting the fake dependency chain to `b c d: a` and that seemed to work. Is it guaranteed to? I'd say yes, since `a` must be made first and when the program finishes, b, c and d are already made and no further invocation necessary. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: The problem with these methods is that if you delete `c` without deleting `a`, `c` won't get rebuilt because there's no rule that knows how to build `c`.